# Module php-cuong customer avatar

Tags: php, magento2, image-upload

I just installed php-cuong customer avatar (https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-customer-avatar) on magento 2.1.8

My problem is that when I want to upload an image in customer panel it has error and not to upload image. In the admin panel, customer tab when I choose a customer and upload image it saves in pub/media but not show avatar and sends error.

Answer (score 0):

CustomerProfilePicture/Model/Attribute/Backend/Avatar.php

In this file there is one function

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
  {
```

just add

```
     if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
```

this if condition , and you are done
because you are getting undefined index error for 
   $dataSource['data']['items']

Comment: Thanks for your response but there is nut this function on it... it has just public function beforeSave($object)

Comment: No error. it just doesnt work. are you installed the extension?  Edit Account Information  is empty and noting to show. in admin panel i can upload image but in front cant upload and also cant see my avatar anywhere

Comment: yes i have installed it, its working fine for Magento CE 2.2.2

Comment: i am using magento 2.1.9. may i have some screenshots of your installation? could you please install it on 2.1.9? i know that it is big request but if it is possible... thank you

Comment: did u install using composer ?

Comment: I installed in 2 different instance. once via composer and once with the cloning (download zip) but same final they have!

Comment: have you used any theme? or default magento theme?

Comment: go to vendor/module-customer/Model/FileUploader.php

Find   

          $result['tmp_name'] = $result['path'] . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');

and replace with 

         $result['tmp_name'] = ltrim($result['file'], '/');

And you are ready to Go!!!!

i have added one more answer

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your kind response, i did it before. after that below things will happend: 1- if you add an avatar via admin panel -> customer, then you can't see account information detail in frontend customer account. but avatar is upload in pub/media/customer and you can see it in admin panel. 2- if you upload an avatar from frontend customer dashboard, you can choose your avatar you want but after click on upload avatar button, nothing will happened and no image will upload in pub/... may i have your skype id to solve it faster?

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
 vendor/module-customer/Model/FileUploader.php
```

Find

```
 $result['tmp_name'] = $result['path'] . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
```

and replace with

```
 $result['tmp_name'] = ltrim($result['file'], '/');
```

And you are ready to Go!!!!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your kind response, i did it before. after that below things will happend: 1- if you add an avatar via admin panel -> customer, then you can't see account information detail in frontend customer account. but avatar is upload in pub/media/customer and you can see it in admin panel. 2- if you upload an avatar from frontend customer dashboard, you can choose your avatar you want but after click on upload avatar button, nothing will happened and no image will upload in pub/... may i have your skype id to solve it faster?